# NA Error min Function in R

Tags: r

I am running into an error using R's min() function.

```
wip <- read.csv("WIP-01-11-11.csv") # Get WIP CSV
wip <- transform(wip, End.Date=as.Date(wip$End.Date,format='%d-%b-%y', na.rm=T))
wip <- transform(wip, Start.Date=as.Date(wip$Start.Date,format='%d-%b-%y', na.rm=T))
wip2 <- transform(wip, duration=ifelse(
                       round((wip3$End.Date - wip3$Start.Date)/30, digits = 0)==0, 
                           1,
                          round((wip3$End.Date - wip3$Start.Date)/30, digits = 0))) 
               # At this point, I get NAs
wip3 <- transform(wip2, monthsRec=min( ( 
               (2011*12+11) - as.numeric(format(wip3$Start.Date, '%Y'))*12 +
                              as.numeric(format(wip3$Start.Date, '%m'))), 
               wip3$duration)
                 )
```

Why am I getting NAs in the "duration"  calculation for wip2 when End.Date and Start.Date have no NAs.

Thanks,

Comment: I don't think the `na.rm=T` bits in your code do what you think they do. IOW, you still have NAs, although you may think you've removed them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
wip3 = list()
wip3$Start.Date = as.Date('2011-01-01')
wip3$duration = 10
> min(((2011*12+11) - as.numeric(format(wip3$Start.Date, '%Y'))*12+as.numeric(format(wip3$Start.Date, '%m'))),wip3$duration)
[1] 10
```

Works fine for me. Do you have any NAs in your data? If so, you probably want to use the `na.rm=T` flag to `min()`.

Comment: Thanks John but here are no NAs in the data. Using the na.rm=T, gives me a result of '1', which isn't what I'm looking for.

Comment: @AME to be of any more help, beyond assuming you have the very common problem I mentioned above, we're going to need to see a subset of your data that will reproduce the problem.

Comment: @AME if your result changed with `na.rm=T`, then that means there *are* NAs in your data. They might be getting introduced by the nested functions, but they are there. If you aren't expecting any, you should work through the different parts of you main statement to see where things are going haywire.

Comment: I think you're on to something, I am getting errors in my calculation for "Duration" (see code above). Any idea why?

Comment: @AME: I don't downvote very often but this refusal to produce reproducible data has me really close.

Answer (score 1):

I reproduced your problem with @John Colbys example if I use the wrong casing for `wip3$start.Date`:

```
wip3 = list()
wip3$start.Date = as.Date('2011-01-01')
wip3$duration = 10
min(((2011*12+11) - as.numeric(format(wip3$Start.Date, '%Y'))*12+as.numeric(format(wip3$Start.Date, '%m'))),wip3$duration)
```

Which produces

```
[1] NA
Warning messages:
1: NAs introduced by coercion 
2: NAs introduced by coercion
```

I suspected since you have `wip3$duration`, you probably have `wip3$start.Date` too - but you accessed it as `wip3$Start.Date` in your code. That returns `NULL`, which doesn't work well with the rest...

Comment: Good observation but the casing doesn't seem to be the issue. Thanks.

Comment: @AME - I see you updated your question. If duration has NAs, could your try `wip3[which(is.na(wip3$duration)), ]` which should show the rows that have problems...